# get next and previous entry in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get the next and previous items (title and image) for each topic and I have this for next and previous links:

```
$currentUser = PostTranslation::find($post->id);

$previousUserID = PostTranslation::where('id', '<', $currentUser->id)->max('id');

$nextUserID = PostTranslation::where('id', '>', $currentUser->id)->min('id');
```

but it's just get the next and previous link id, which I need to get the title for them too. I have used this:

```
$previousUserID2 = PostTranslation::find($currentUser->id-1);
```

but it's when `id = 0` that I am getting an error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27942973/465388

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dataset is too big max and min can slow down your sql.

You can use `first` along with `orderby` which retrieve the first model matching the query constraints.

```
   $currentUser = PostTranslation::find($post->id);
   //order by descending order and take the first entry
   $previousUser = PostTranslation::where('id', '<', $currentUser->id)->select('id','title')->orderby('id','desc')->first();
   $previous_id=$previousUser ->id;
   $previous_title=$previousUser ->title;
   //order by ascending order and take the first entry
   $nextUser = PostTranslation::where('id', '>', $currentUser->id)->select('id','title')->orderby('id','asc')->first();
   $next_id=$nextUser ->id;
   $next_title=$nextUser ->title;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , it has been solved with me , but still have an issue with the last record which when i'm at the first record or last one i'm having this error :Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @DinaShaldoum You've just got to write in some checks, for example. `if($previousUser) // Do your stuff here`.

Answer (score 0):

That's last code i have been used at my controller :

```
$previousUser = PostTranslation::join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_translations.post_id')
        ->where('posts.id', '<', $currentUser->id)
        ->select('posts.id','post_translations.title','post_image')
        ->orderby('posts.id','desc')
        ->where('post_translations.language', $language)
        ->first();
```

Comment: i have written  if($previousUser)  before calling the data at my view and it's solved ..

Comment: This is copy of my answer , you should mark the correct answer instead of  copying the answer , it wont help anybody