# Laravel next and prev pagination post

Tags: php, laravel

In post, when I read post I have two button next post, and prev post. I want do this buttons and redirect user to next post or prev post. How I can do this correctly?

I have url post: `http://example.com/post/1`

```
   <div class="entry-navigation">
      {{-- <div class="column text-left"><a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" href="{{ route('postshow', $offer->id - 1) }}"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp;Prev</a></div> --}}
      <div class="column"><a class="btn btn-outline-secondary view-all" href="{{ route('offers') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="All posts"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a></div>
      {{-- <div class="column text-right"><a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" href="{{ route('postshow', $offer->id + 1) }}">Next&nbsp;<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a></div> --}}
    </div>
```

I think with `route` id +/- 1 I can do. But how I can check if post not deleted, or if he exists?

I can use and `paginate`:

```
$posts = Post::active()->where('id', '!=', $post->id)->paginate(1);
```

But I get other links with `?page=1` .. `?page=10`  
How I get full link to next or prev post ?

Comment: I think it's better to use pagination with limit 1 for fetching your resource, then you have access to next and prev link. I you don't want to use pagination, then you should have methods to get prev and next id from your model. otherwise you have to implement many logic on your view.

Comment: @train_fox see please updated question

Comment: On paginate response what you need are `next_page_url` and `prev_page_url`. Don't worry about absolute url cause laravel fills it by your .env config.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel previous and next records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909706/laravel-previous-and-next-records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting a answer because i i dont have enough reputation.

Here is a link that can help you : [Laravel previous and next records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909706/laravel-previous-and-next-records/27942973)

I think its a duplicated question