# Query for the next/previous element in an ordered collection

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-collection

There exists an `Invoice`-object that has a id. It correlates to a `Bank` in a `Bank->hasManyThrough(Invoice::class, InvoiceData::class)`-relationship.

I now have an arbitrary `Invoice`-object and want to find the next and the previous one (`created_at`) that relates to the same `Bank`.

I wonder if there is an elegant query that can give me the next/previous object without iterating over a collection. Something like:

```
 $bank->hasManyThrough(Invoice::class, InvoiceData::class)
     ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
     ->get($invoice->id)
     ->next();
```

Comment: you can check out this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909706/laravel-previous-and-next-records

Comment: This doesn't work if there are multiple value which are created at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query I was searching for was actually this:

```
$bank->hasManyThrough(Invoice::class, InvoiceData::class)
    ->latest()
    ->where("id", "<", $invoice->id)
    ->first();
```

Filtering by everything that has a greater or smaller `id` prevents that the query gets stuck on objects which are created at the same time.